# Bearer Token for angular in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

the scenario is very simple 
I am using the custom login for sake of simplicity to generate bearer token for angular I have done my research on google, but I wonder why there is no simple example on this issue

below is the code :

```
 public class IdentityController : ApiController
    {
        IdentityController()
        {
            OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        }
        public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult login([FromBody]LoginModel user)
        {
            var username = user.Username.ToLower();
            var password = user.Password;

            if (username == "admin" && password == "1234")
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(username);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(principal);
                if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
                }

                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
                var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
                ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
                ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(30));



                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username , false);
                var result = new { authenticatonToke = OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket) };
                return Ok(result);
            }

            else return BadRequest("wrong user name or password");
        }

    }
```

I get null reference error on

```
OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket)
```

because AccessTokenFormat is null

is there any other possible workaround to generate bearer token in web API?
I don't want to use asp.net identity or any other thing .. is just if admin and password is 1234 . and when I get the bearer token I want to use it in postman

Comment: this: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/01/15/using-json-web-tokens-with-katana-and-webapi.aspx might help you to setup  AccessTokenFormat

Answer (score 0):

I will strongly recommend you to use [Identity Server](https://identityserver.github.io/) to generate tokens, manage users/clients etc. You can also find several OpenId certified solutions in this [page](http://openid.net/developers/certified/)

Federated security is an important topic. In-house solutions may have problems with 3rd parties.

Comment: i know , it is just for purpuse of testing . security is not in scope of application i am building .

Comment: It may be worth to spend some time on their github page.  TokenResponseGenerator.cs may be helpful for your question.

Comment: [This Library](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt) also may help you to create encrypted tokens.